# How to schedule repeat-notification every 2 second after particular time period?

Tags: swift, usernotifications

//this method start send notification after one minutes , i want method for start notification after given time period and repeat itself after 2 second.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    let notification = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notification.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]){ isAccess, error in
            if isAccess , error == nil {
                var second = 60
                for _ in 0...31 {
                    self.sendNotificationOnDate(second: &second)
                }
            }
            else{
                print("not access")
            }
        }
        notification.delegate = self
    }
    
    func sendNotificationOnDate(second: inout Int){
        let id = UUID().uuidString
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        
        content.title =  "Alarm present"
        content.body = " Alarm \(second)"
        content.sound = .default
        content.threadIdentifier = ""
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(second) ,  repeats: false)
        second += 2
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        notification.add(request) { error in
            self.notification.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, according to the docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger/1649777-init , "...the value in the timeInterval parameter must be 60 seconds or greater." when the `repeats` is set to true. I wonder if this is not a system wide limit. Although you set yours to false.

Comment: Yes, you are right  but my point is start after particular time period like: 3 to 4 hour later.
but in this case i set "repeat: true " then notification trigger every 2 second after one minute later.